# Return from a loop on a condition

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following function:

```
(defun chooseBest (TSPs dTSPs)
    (let ((minim (minPos dTSPs 0 0)) (j 0) (best nil)) 
        (loop for i in TSPs
             do (cond ((= j minim) (progn (setf best i) (setq j (+ j 1))))
                      (t (setq j (+ j 1)))))        
        best))
```

This function receives two lists:

TSPs - a list of paths like this one:

```
(((1 3600 2300) (2 3100 3300))
 ((3 4700 5750) (22 6650 2300) (23 5400 1600)))
```

and a list of distances associated with these:

```
(distancePath1 distancePath2)
```

The function `minPos` returns the position of the list with a smaller number that is the path with smaller distance.

Given this, the `chooseBest` function will return the smaller path.

But I want to improve it, because it will search the whole list for the small number and it is a waste because the `minim` has that position. For example `minim` is 2, but it is evaluating a TSPs list with 100 paths, I want to return immediately on 2 and break the loop, but return doesn't work...

Comment: Many loop examples with conditionals and `return`: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html and functions to search elements in sequences (find, search, elt, index, nth… https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rework your function a bit.

First, with better **indentation**:

```
(defun chooseBest (TSPs dTSPs)
  (let ((minim (minPos dTSPs 0 0))
        (j 0)
        (best nil))
    (loop for i in TSPs
       do (cond ((= j minim)
                 (progn (setf best i)
                        (setq j (+ j 1))))
                (t 
                 (setq j (+ j 1)))))
    best))
```

No need of the `progn` inside the `cond`:

```
       do (cond ((= j minim)
                 (setf best i)
                 (setq j (+ j 1)))
                (t 
                 (setq j (+ j 1)))))
```

**Incrementing j** can be done with `incf`:

```
                 (setq j (+ j 1)))
```

=>

```
                 (incf j)
```

You can move the **let variables** into the **loop**.

```
  (let ((minim (minPos dTSPs 0 0))
        (j 0)
        (best nil))
    (loop for i in TSPs
```

=>

```
(loop for it in TSPs
      for j from 0
      with minim = (minPos dTSPs 0 0)
      with best
      do …)
```

`for j from 0` starts a counter, `with … =` declares a variable which is calculated at the beginning (and not at every iteration).

**Returns and conditionals**

Inside a loop, we can use `if…do`, `else…do`, `when` and `return`, and more than once. To do something at the end of the loop, use `finally`.

```
(defun chooseBest (TSPs dTSPs)
  (loop for i in TSPs
     for j from 0
     with minim = (minPos dTSPs 0 0)
     with best
     if (= j minim)
     do (progn (setf best i)
               (incf j))
     else
     do (incf j)
     finally (return best)))
```

---

**Functions to search lists and sequences**

Now if you want to find an element inside a list, you have lots of functions for that: find, nth, search, position,… see https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#functions Since `minPos` returns an index, you probably want `nth index list` or `elt sequence index`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *nth* element of a list, you can use the function `nth`: `(nth position list)`

```
CL-USER 15 > (nth 0 '(((1 3600 2300) (2 3100 3300))
                      ((3 4700 5750) (22 6650 2300) (23 5400 1600))))
((1 3600 2300) (2 3100 3300))

CL-USER 16 > (nth 1 '(((1 3600 2300) (2 3100 3300))
                      ((3 4700 5750) (22 6650 2300) (23 5400 1600))))
((3 4700 5750) (22 6650 2300) (23 5400 1600))
```

If you want to return from a loop, you can use the operator `return`:

```
CL-USER > (loop for i from 10
                when (= i (expt (isqrt i) 2))
                do (return i))
16
```